# How to retrieve Mysql data from todays date using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am using the PHP time() function to get the current time and Insert it into the database.
I can also retrieve date  by setting the value in a variable and doing something like: `date(Y-m-d, $time)`
But now I want to get a result from the Database on the current date compared to the time inserted in the Database

I have tried:

```
SELECT sum(amount) as today_sales FROM activity WHERE type = 'debit' AND `time` = DATE(NOW())
```

But this query doesn't work. It still displays 0 as a result

Comment: Share the codes that you tried

Comment: SELECT sum(amount) as today_sales FROM activity WHERE type2 = 'debit' AND 'time' = DATE(NOW())

Comment: Try running SELECT NOW() and check whther you db and webserver is on same timezone

Comment: Do you have access to phpmyadmin ?

Comment: You're using apostrophes around `time` but you should be using backticks.

Comment: Yes i have access to phpmyadmin

Comment: Can you use the query i gave to show example please?

Comment: As @TangentiallyPerpendicular mentioned, you're using ' to delimit the column `time` while you should be using the backtick. So ``SELECT sum(amount) as today_sales FROM activity WHERE type = 'debit' AND `time` = DATE(NOW())`` should work

Comment: Please explain "doesn't work" in technical terms.

Comment: It still displays 0 as result

Comment: I am trying to sum up balance values from a table.
Everything works fine except from getting the result on today's date only.
I am using time() function to store the date and time.
Now i am trying to get the sum from current date.
When i try SELECT sum(amount) as today_sales
  FROM activity WHERE type = 'debit' AND `time` = DATE(NOW()), It returns Zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong quotes. `'` is for *string data only*.

```sql
SELECT sum(amount) as today_sales
  FROM activity WHERE type = 'debit' AND `time` = DATE(NOW())
```

Here `'debit'` is a string. `time` is a column name, it uses [identifier quotes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html).

What your query was doing was comparing the literal string `'time'` to the current date, which of course will never match.

> Tip: It's generally a bad idea to have column names that conflict with [reserved keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) which avoids a lot of this escaping mess in the first place.

Comment: Nah, still dosent work, It still displays 0 as result . But i have few data in time column on same date

Comment: Please **do not** say that, it's extremely frustrating because it tells us nothing about the problem. Describe in technical terms what happens.

Comment: I am trying to sum up balance values from a table.
Everything works fine except from getting the result on today's date only.
I am using time() function to store the date and time.
Now i am trying to get the sum from current date.
When i try SELECT sum(amount) as today_sales
  FROM activity WHERE type = 'debit' AND `time` = DATE(NOW()), It returns Zero

Comment: What is in the `time` column? What kind of values? I'd guess *time* values, as in they're never going to precisely equal today's *date*. Maybe `DATE(\`time\`) = DATE(NOW())`?

Comment: I insert into database by $time=time();. The column name is time. The values comes out as integar

Comment: You want a [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) column to make it a lot more usable, which means insert as `NOW()` instead, or use PHP `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` instead. `time()` is a UNIX timestamp which isn't the same thing at all, as it can't be easily used in functions like `DATE()`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation to your problem. We can usually figure it out if given just enough detail.